# Get varbinary from sql server and send to outputstream in xpages

Tags: java, sql-server, binary, xpages, outputstream

I used this command to store a zip file as varbinary(max) in an sql server:

```
INSERT INTO Cache(name,zip)
SELECT 'my_zip_file1',* FROM 
    OPENROWSET(BULK N'D:\folder\fol2\my_zip_file.zip', SINGLE_BLOB) AS import;
```

and it successfully stores the name and binary data in the table named Cache.

In my `xpage` I have a button that sends to another download page with `render=false` and 1 line of code to `beforeRenderResponse` event in order to execute a java managed bean (i.e `dl.download()`).

I have managed to use jdbc from managed beans so as to get and store data from relational db such as db2 and sql server.

In this particular case I want to know how can I get the binary data from the db? Using `rs.getBytes` or `rs.getBinaryStream` ?

How can I send it to http response output?
Below I am pasting the code that fails:

```
public void download(String filepath) {
    Connection con;
    PreparedStatement stm;
    ResultSet rs;
    byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
    //InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(buf);
    byte[] zip;
    try {
        Class.forName(jdbcClass);
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        String sql = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Cache where name = ?;";
        stm = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        stm.setString(1, "D:\\folder\\fol2\\my_zip_file.zip");
        rs = stm.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            zip = rs.getBytes("zip");
            ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(zip);

            //System.out.println("AVAIL:"+zip.available());
            FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            ExternalContext externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();
            HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) externalContext.getResponse();
            response.setContentType("application/zip, application/octet-stream");
            response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=z.zip");
            response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
            ServletOutputStream sout = response.getOutputStream();

            int c = 0;
            //while ((c = is.read()) > 0) {
            while ((c = is.read(buf, 0, buf.length)) > 0) {
                //sout.write(c);
                sout.write(buf, 0, c);
                //sout.flush();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

The error is:

> cant get writer while outputstream is used.

Trying another version of the code gave me the error:

> output stream is closed

Any ideas?

PS: I have managed to make it work with a text file. I got a string from the db and sent a file containing this string to the outputstream. It was downloaded from the browser and everything was ok. The problem is with binary files as zip...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you have to close response.

```
facesContext.responseComplete();
```